# Why does row reducing a matrix argumented with the identity turn the argumented part into the inverse when you're done?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a matrix A and [A|B] denotes the matrix A argumented (B bolted on the right) with B.

If you row reduce [A|I] you get [I|$A^{-1}$] I get mental glimpses of why it makes sense (row operations "do nothing", they just re-write stuff) and geometrically I also get flashes, but I couldn't explain why!

Now the above is probably a recurring question, I wish I knew what it was called, if you can't explain it please give me some way to search for something that will.

**The interesting part of the question**

I can't do Matrices well in LaTeX yet, also I don't think it matters to the question, I am inquiring about the general case after all!

Consider the (3x3 matrix in my specific case) A, det(A)=1 (so it has an inverse)

Then consider [A|B] where B is a 3x2 matrix (3 rows, 2 columns), if you think of this as 2 vectors of length 3, they are linearly independent of each other.

The row reduced form of [A|B] is equal to $A^{-1}$[A|B]

Now I am not stupid/lazy and I like to think of a 3xn matrix as a list of n vectors, and a 3x3 (non-singular) matrix as a linear transform.

It then makes sense that $A^{-1}$ maps the column space (I think it is called? I have come at this from the intuitive side, my formal side is weak) of A to the identity, this is sort of its job.

If you have $A^{-1}A(1,0,0)^T$ A maps (1,0,0) to the first column, and $A^{-1}$ takes it back

However I am not sure why the "B part" is mapped to the same part of the matrix (last 2 columns) under this transformation.

I'm also able to visualise 3 dimensions, I'd like to be confident about this, rather than using thought.

Answer (score 2):

When you perform a row operation, you are multiplying on the left by some suitable matrix. Multiply all the row operations together and call the result $L$.

Then the matrix $[A|I]$ will become $[LA|L]$, and if $LA=I$, then we have $L=A^{-1}$, and so $L[A|I] = [LA|L] = [I|A^{-1}]$.

Similarly, if we have $[A|B]$, and $LA=I$, we will have
$L=A^{-1}$, and so $L[A|B] = [LA|LB] = [I|A^{-1}B]$.

Comment: That covers the first part brilliantly, not so much the second, remember B is a 3x2 matrix (3 rows, 2 columns), I can't see why $A^{-1}[A|B]=[I|A^{-1}B]=Rref[A|B]$, but you really helped with the first part, it seems obvious now!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it works in exactly the same way. I have elaborated above, hopefully this answers your question.